# différence entre « de » et « des »

Tags: usage

Il est clair que, par exemple, lorsque l'on dit « de gros chiens » et « des gros chiens » on dit à peu près la même chose. Y a-t-il vraiment une différence entre les deux?

Comment: Je ne sais pas si j'ai bien compris. On dit : "J'ai des gros chiens" et il faut dire "Je n'ai pas de gros chiens". En oral, la tendance est de dire "Je n'ai pas des gros chiens" (on rencontre cette situation même dans la langue écrite). On dit encore "Beaucoup de gros chiens sont dangereux" et "Beaucoup des gros chiens de la ville sont morts".

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris votre question, je vais écrire une réponse:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Oui, je connais les formes que vous mentionnez et je les utilise de la façon dont vous le faites; cependant il pourrait y avoir une différence par exemple entre « Il y avait de grands bâtiments au bout de la rue. » et « Il y avait des grands bâtiments au bout de la rue. », ces deux possibilités étant correctes, du moins il me le semble, et voulant apparemment dire la même chose; est-ce exactement la même chose mis à part que la première possibilité serait  presque seulement  littéraire ?

Comment: @dimitris Je crois saisir une différence maintenant dans un contexte que vous abordez ; on doit dire « Je n'ai pas de gros chiens.» lorsqu' il s'agit de dire que l'on n'a pas de chien qui soient gros, comme vous le remarquez; il semble que l'on puisse dire « Je n'ai pas des gros chiens mais ils sont méchants. » lorsque on veut dire que les chiens que l'on a ne sont pas gros. Je n'ai pas certitude en ce qui concerne cette dernière interprétation, cependant et ne peut pas en faire une réponse.

Comment: Je viens de donner une réponse. D'après la grammaire consultée la phrase " Il y avait de grands bâtiments au bout de la rue. " me paraît plus correcte.

Comment: @dimitis Ça me parait seulement plus élégant et cette notion n'a toujours été chez moi que très subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans le français écrit et, généralement, dans le français parlé un peu surveillé, *de* remplace *des* devant un adjectif pluriel :

> On voyait *de* grands navires.

La langue parlée (et même la langue écrite) prennent d'ailleurs ici beaucoup de libertés :

> Ils auraient (...) **de** chauds pantalons de velours et **des** gros souliers...(G. Perec, Les Choses).

Et, même en français écrit, *des* reparaît, si le groupe adjectif-nom forme un tout, et notamment un nom composé :

> Des jeunes gens et des jeunes filles.
>
> Des grands-parents et des petits-enfants.
>
> Des petits pois.
>
> Des faux billets.
>
> Des grosses légumes.

De restituerait à l'adjectif sa valeur première, son autonomie :

> De grands enfants.

Source: G. Mauger Grammaire pratique du français d'aujourd'hui.

Comment: Encore un effort : la liasse *de* faux billets qui est sur le frigo vs la liasse *des* faux billets qui est sur le frigo. Ou encore, la boite *de* petits pois sur la cheminée vs la boite *des* petits pois qui est sur la cheminée. ;) Et pour finir : la bande de jeunes du quartier vs la bande des jeunes du quartier. Bref, avec *de* c'est en vrac (de la fraise, du jeune), mais avec *des* on sait de qui on parle (des fraises du jardin ou des jeunes du quartier). Idem pour les chiens : il a de gros chiens (de sales bêtes quoi), il a des gros chiens (purée, je les ai vu, y font pas rire).