# Avoir de & Avoir

Tags: grammaire, sens

I read a vocabulary book which has this sentence «  le langage a d'innombrables expressions » 
Why don’t we write « le langage a des innombrables expressions »? 
Even we also write «  Il a des enfants »

Comment: C'est bien cette question qui contient la réponse (Elle a de/des longs cheveux).

Answer (score 3):

Voir aussi la discussion ici :

[différence entre « de » et « des »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31513/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-de-et-des/31517#31517)

I repeat my response here accompanied by a translation in English.

Dans le français écrit et, généralement, dans le français parlé un peu surveillé, de remplace des devant un adjectif pluriel. In written French and, generally, in spoken French a little guarded, de replaces des in front of a plural adjective:

> On voyait de grands navires.

La langue parlée (et même la langue écrite) prennent d'ailleurs ici beaucoup de libertés. The spoken language (and even the written language) take here a lot of liberties:

> Ils auraient (...) de chauds pantalons de velours et des gros souliers...(G. Perec, Les Choses).

Et, même en français écrit, des reparaît, si la groupe adjectif-nom forme un tout, et notamment un nom composé. And, even in written French, des reappears, if the group adjective-noun forms a whole, and in particular a compound name:

> Des jeunes gens et des jeunes filles.
>
> Des grands-parents et des petits-enfants.
>
> Des petits pois.
>
> Des faux billets.
>
> Des grosses légumes.

De restituerait à l'adjectif sa valeur première, son autonomie. De would restore to the adjective its primary value, its autonomy:

> De grands enfants.

**Source: G. Mauger Grammaire pratique du français d'aujourd'hui.**

---

There is also a pertinent and very interesting comment by the user @jcm69

Encore un effort : la liasse de faux billets qui est sur le frigo vs la liasse des faux billets qui est sur le frigo. Ou encore, la boite de petits pois sur la cheminée vs la boite des petits pois qui est sur la cheminée. ;) Et pour finir : la bande de jeunes du quartier vs la bande des jeunes du quartier. Bref, avec de c'est en vrac (de la fraise, du jeune), mais avec des on sait de qui on parle (des fraises du jardin ou des jeunes du quartier). Idem pour les chiens : il a de gros chiens (de sales bêtes quoi), il a des gros chiens (purée, je les ai vu, y font pas rire).